# How to shorten conjugations of "must" forms without sounding girly?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, gender

I know the full conjugations of expressing things that must/must not be done (ex:行かなくてはだめ）and their slang forms (ex:行かなくちゃ) but I've heard the ちゃ sounds like a little girl speaking? If that's true, how can I shorten the full conjugation without using ちゃ?

Comment: 行かないと。 is a good alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing it.
Looking at 行く as the verb.

> 行かなくてはいけません
>   行かなければなりません
>   行かなくてはいけない
>   行かなければならない
>   行かなくちゃいけない (mostly feminine)
>   行かなきゃいけない (mostly feminine)
>   行かなくちゃ (mostly feminine)
>   行かなきゃ (mostly feminine)
>   行かないと
>   行かんと (informal, colloquial)

Similarly with する as the verb

> しなくてはいけません
>   しなければなりません
>   しなくてはいけない
>   しなければならない
>   しなくちゃいけない (mostly feminine)
>   しなきゃいけない (mostly feminine)
>   しなくちゃ (mostly feminine)
>   しなきゃ (mostly feminine)
>   しないと
>   せんと (informal, colloquial, dialect)

Comment: You could list 〜なきゃ too.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that one. I will add it now.

Comment: @snailboat The OP explicitly said he did not want to sound girly.

Comment: @oldergod I would disagree at なきゃ sounding girly **all** the time. However, for completeness sake (and because I have heard it used by a majority of females over males) I will note it.

Comment: I think なきゃ is used quite often by both males and females.  Most speakers I asked seemed to agree with that impression, but I guess "sound girly" is subjective.

Comment: I think you also need to account for regional variations as well. Saying something with a ～わ on the end is a feminine thing to do everywhere except the Kansai area, where it is used equally with females and males. I would imagine that there is a subset region where ～なきゃ is overtly feminine and otherwise completely normal somewhere else.