# meaning of なくっちゃ

Tags: translation

I am reading a children's book lent by a friend, and I came across a word that did not appear in the dictionary I use (jisho.org) or in any google searches.
The word is なくっちゃ。

The sentence it is used in is:
おいしい　りんごは　らいねんまで　またなくっちゃ。

I think it has something to do with receiving again maybe, but that also is a bit strange....

Thanks for the help!

PS: I don't think また is part of it, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28334/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24353/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2500/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4213/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> またなくっちゃ

It's a colloquial variation of:

待たなくては(いけない） You have to wait (until~).

Comment: Are mata and nakuteha separate or one word?

Comment: It's the verb 待つ (matsu), conjugated into the negative 待たない (matanai), which is then further conjugated into 待たなくて (matanakute), with the particle は (wa) at the end.